# Dynamically build a int[] array from the database

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to build a int[] array from returned values from the database,

Normally for an int[] array that isn't database driven you would do something like this:

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };
```

my public variable is as follows:

```
public int[] SelectedItems { get; set; } // Which is used for the multi select list box
```

I then when retrieving the values do something like this:

```
model.SelectedItems = (from x in collection select x.Id).ToArray();
```

but I get the error:

Cannot convert source type 'dynamic[]' to target type 'int[]'

I have googled this error but with no avail.

My collection looks like this:

```
public class UserActivities
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ActivityDesc { get; set; }
}
```

*Update*

I'm using dapper.net to retrieve the values so once I've made the call to the DB I then read it as follows:

```
var activities = sqlCon.Read().ToList();
```

I use this in two places, first place I display the string description which is shown on the page for the user, the Id's I try to reference and build an array which is used else where in the application.

Comment: "My collection looks like this: ..." That's your collection element, not your collection. How does the `collection` variable in `from x in collection` is declared?

Comment: Please add the full declaration of `collection` to your question. It would seem that it is not an `IQueryable<UserActivities>`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've added an update.

Comment: did you do the call to the database using `connection.Query<UserActivities>(" your sql statement here", new [] { your query parameters here });` ?

Comment: @Alex no, its a multiple query, I retrieve values from the user profile table first, and then I make a second call to the Activities table and return the activities that are linked to the user,as he/she can chose as many as they like

Comment: It might be helpful if you include the way in which you perform the query in your question, as that determines its result value, which you use later on. If it was a `QueryMultiple`, you should use `Read<UserActivities>().ToList()`.

Comment: @Alex your read example you showed me worked a treat, I totally forgot about model binding with Dapper.Net! its working as expected now.

Comment: For the record - so you can communicate more clearly in the future, you are talking about an `int[]`, an `array of int`, or an `int array`.  `int[] array` would mean an array of int arrays.

Comment: Ok, I added this as an answer, so the question can be wrapped up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `(from x in collection select x.Id)` requires an `IEnumerable<UserActivities>` or `IQueryable<UserActivities>` as the type for the `collection` variable. The error you are getting is because `collection` seems to be an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.

Given that you mentioned in your edit and the comments that you are using Dapper.NET and the query is performed using the `QueryMultiple` method, you will need to get the result set with elements of type `UserActivities`.

This can be achieved using

```
var collection = sqlCon.Read<UserActivities>().ToList();
```

which will extract that result set from the multiple query result.